Gray Area: semi-link-only answers
While parsing through the review queues, I’ve encountered a few answers that primarily consist of links, but not entirely. I’m seeking advice on the best approach to address these. Some options I've considered are:
This would be my preference.

Leaving a comment: I’ve often left comments requesting the author to
enhance their answer with some context or a summary of the linked
content. It would be helpful to have a set of standard comments for
such situations, or a link to guide them on how to summarize linked
content. The tour doesn’t exactly cover this.



Editing the answer: While editing the answer to add context or
summarize the linked content can be beneficial, it can also be
time-consuming, especially when one needs to familiarize themselves
with the linked content. However, the upside is that this could
enhance the answer’s usefulness and help prevent link rot.
Downvoting: Should an answer be downvoted if it doesn’t provide
sufficient information beyond the link? I confess to being a sparing
downvoter. (Perhaps I shouldn't be). Personally, I prefer to
leave a comment for new users, giving them the chance to improve
their answer.
Flagging the answer: Would a custom flag be appropriate? Probably
not, right? However, if the answer is brief enough, it might be suitable for
conversion to a comment. In my view, flagging is only justified if
the answer doesn’t attempt to answer the question at all without
the linked content.


To me, I would generally commend most of these as appropriate responses - and to be honest, given the diversity among the community I think we have different tendencies towards certain types of actions. Thanks for flagging this concern.
Personally:

Editing feels like a potential waste of time for this type of issue, as it does take a lot of effort and probably isn't helping the OP to improve their post quality. Though editing most other types of issue can be helpful!

Leaving a comment is always a good response where an issue is observed that needs to be worked on. The more that the community does this for people the better the new user experience will/should be.

Downvoting is a good concrete way to indicate to the user, system and community that the post needs work. I thoroughly agree that we don't downvote enough across the community! I'd personally weight the decision according to the other Answers and its relative value in its current state. As long as it's coupled with a Comment to explain why, and perhaps an affirmation that you'd be happy to reverse it if they update it, this is a fair response.

Custom flags are always an appropriate response if you don't feel like you have the tools or resources to get any job done. We view Moderation as a community activity, and it takes all of us together to get it right. Feel free to use them wherever you want a second pair of eyes on something.


As a side note in that last one, the Abusive and Low Quality flags are a bit special and so we will decline those where they're not warranted, as they have negative implications for the target user. But more often than not we tend to accept most/all custom flags as Helpful, and will provide responses where appropriate.
The more work the community does to help manage content quality, the better an experience new users have and they don't feel like they're always getting 'smacked down' by Moderators, so we're all fans of people chipping in to do whatever you can to help!

Personally I'd accept a VLQ flag for an ultra short or link only answer. Custom flags are fine too.
